# How to write this python code in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Print number if each and every element of number is even:

```
a=[111,222,333,444,232,343]
count =0
b = []
for i in a:
    for j in str(i):
        if int(j) % 2 == 0:
            count +=1
            if count == len(str(i)):
                b.append(i)
        else:
            count = 0
            break
print b
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730418/how-do-i-write-the-list-comprehension-for-the-given-code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This list comprehension works:

```
b = [i for i in a if all(int(j)%2 == 0 for j in set(str(i)))]

>>> b
[222, 444]
```

It includes casting to set, so that you only look at the unique characters making up each element. Also, it uses `all` to check that each character in that set is even.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use filter：

```
b = list(filter(lambda x: all(int(i)%2 == 0 for i in set(str(x))), a))
```